# Cover execute method of a Batch class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage

first of all thank you for your time, i need some help to cover this batch class, right now the test class i will post bellow only covers the finish method and the get; set; .

**CLASS**:

```
global class DirectDebitBatch implements Database.Batchable < sObject > , Database.Stateful {

global final String query;
global List < AccountAmount > accounts;
global String errors;
global List<Bank_Statement__c> finalBankStatementList;

public class AccountAmount {

    public Id accountId {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String accountName {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string sortCode {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String accountNumber {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Decimal amount {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List < Invoice_Header__c > invoicesToBePaid {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public String error { 
        get;
        set;
    }

    public AccountAmount(Id accountId, String accountName, String sortCode, String accountNumber, Decimal amount, List < Invoice_Header__c > invoicesToBePaid) {

        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.sortCode = sortCode;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.invoicesToBePaid = invoicesToBePaid;
    }
}

global DirectDebitBatch() {
    accounts = new List < AccountAmount > ();
    errors = '';
    finalBankStatementList = new List<Bank_Statement__c>();
    //string today = String.valueOf(system.today());
    query = 'SELECT Name, Payment_Account_Number__c, Payment_Sort_Code__c, (SELECT Id, DueDate__c, AmountOutstanding__c FROM Invoice_Headers__r WHERE AmountOutstanding__c > 0 AND ToPublish__c = true AND Query__c = false AND Overdue_Days__c > 0 AND DueDate__c <= TODAY ) FROM Account WHERE Enqix_Payment_Method__c = \'Direct Debit\' AND Id IN(SELECT Account__c FROM Invoice_Header__c WHERE AmountOutstanding__c > 0 AND ToPublish__c = true AND Query__c = false AND Overdue_Days__c > 0) order by Name limit 6';
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List < sObject > scope) {
    List < Bank_Statement__c > bankStatementsToCreate = new List < Bank_Statement__c > ();
    List < PaymentAllocation__c > paymentAllocationsToCreate = new List < PaymentAllocation__c > ();
    List < Invoice_Header__c > invoiceHeadersToUpdate = new List < Invoice_Header__c > ();
    Map < Id, List < Invoice_Header__c >> accountInvoicesToBePaid = new Map < Id, List < Invoice_Header__c >> ();

    for (SObject s: scope) {
        Account a = (Account) s;
        Bank_Statement__c bs = new Bank_Statement__c();
        bs.Account__c = a.Id;
        bs.Entry_Date__c = System.today();
        bs.Transaction_Details__c = a.Name + ' Direct Debit Payment';
        bs.Transaction_Type__c = 'Direct Debit';
        bs.Document_name__c = 'Direct Debit Remittance ' + System.today();
        bs.IsDirectDebit__c = True;
        /*bs.Payment_Amount__c = bs.AllocAmount__c;
        bs.Receipt_Amount__c = bs.AllocAmount__c;
        bs.Ledger_Balance__c = bs.AllocAmount__c;*/
        bs.Customer_Reference__c = a.Name + bs.Entry_Date__c + ' DD Remittance';
        bankStatementsToCreate.add(bs);
        system.debug(bs);

        Decimal amount = 0;
        for (Invoice_Header__c i: a.Invoice_Headers__r) {
            amount += i.AmountOutstanding__c;
        }
        AccountAmount aa = new AccountAmount(a.Id, a.Name, a.Payment_Sort_Code__c, a.Payment_Account_Number__c, amount, a.Invoice_Headers__r);
        accounts.add(aa);
        accountInvoicesToBePaid.put(a.Id, a.Invoice_Headers__r);
    }




    // USE THE OBJECT LOG TO SAVE THESE INSERTS/UPDATES/ERRORS

    List<LogRegister> logs = new List<LogRegister>();
    String objectType;
    String process;
    String action;
    String recordId;
    String errorMessage;

    Database.SaveResult[] resultsBS = Database.insert(bankStatementsToCreate, false);
    for (Integer idx = 0; idx < resultsBS.size(); idx++) {
        objectType = 'Bank Statement';
        process = 'DirectDebitBatch';
        action = 'INSERT';
        errorMessage = '';
        if (!resultsBS[idx].isSuccess()) {
            recordId = 'Account: '+ bankStatementsToCreate[idx].Account__c;
            for (Database.Error err: resultsBS[idx].getErrors()) {
                errors += 'Account where the error occurred: ' + bankStatementsToCreate[idx].Account__c + ' on Bank Statement creation --- The following error has occurred - ' + err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage() + ' Fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields() + '\n';
                errorMessage += 'The following error has occurred - ' + err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage() + ' Fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields() + '\n';
            }
            LogRegister log = new LogRegister(objectType, process, action, recordId, errorMessage);
            logs.add(log);
        }
        else {
            recordId = resultsBS[idx].getId();
            LogRegister log = new LogRegister(objectType, process, action, recordId, errorMessage);
            logs.add(log);
        }
    }

    for (Bank_Statement__c bs: bankStatementsToCreate) {
        for (Invoice_Header__c i: accountInvoicesToBePaid.get(bs.Account__c)) {
            PaymentAllocation__c pa = new PaymentAllocation__c();
            pa.InvoiceId__c = i.Id;
            pa.BankstatementId__c = bs.Id;
            pa.Account__c = bs.Account__c;
            pa.AllocatedAmount__c = i.AmountOutstanding__c;
            pa.IsDirectDebit__c = true;
            paymentAllocationsToCreate.add(pa);
        }
    }
    Database.SaveResult[] resultsPA = Database.insert(paymentAllocationsToCreate, false);

    for (Integer idx = 0; idx < resultsPA.size(); idx++) {
        if (!resultsPA[idx].isSuccess()) {
            objectType = 'PaymentAllocation';
            process = 'DirectDebitBatch';
            action = 'INSERT';
            errorMessage = '';
            recordId = 'Account: '+ paymentAllocationsToCreate[idx].Account__c;
            for (Database.Error err: resultsPA[idx].getErrors()) {
                errors += 'Account where the error occurred: ' + paymentAllocationsToCreate[idx].Account__c + ' on Bank Statement creation --- The following error has occurred - ' + err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage() + ' Fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields() + '\n';
                errorMessage += 'The following error has occurred - ' + err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage() + ' Fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields() + '\n';
            }
            for (Integer i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
                if (accounts[i].accountId == paymentAllocationsToCreate[idx].Account__c) {
                    accounts.remove(i);
                }
            }
            LogRegister log = new LogRegister(objectType, process, action, recordId, errorMessage);
            logs.add(log);
        }
        else {
            objectType = 'PaymentAllocation';
            process = 'DirectDebitBatch';
            action = 'INSERT';
            errorMessage = '';
            recordId = resultsPA[idx].getId();
            Invoice_Header__c ih = new Invoice_Header__c();
            ih.Id = paymentAllocationsToCreate[idx].InvoiceId__c;
            ih.AmountOutstanding__c = 0; 
            invoiceHeadersToUpdate.add(ih);
            LogRegister log = new LogRegister(objectType, process, action, recordId, errorMessage);
            logs.add(log);
        }
    }

    Database.SaveResult[] resultsIH = Database.update(invoiceHeadersToUpdate, false);
    for (Integer idx = 0; idx < resultsIH.size(); idx++) {
        if (!resultsIH[idx].isSuccess()) {

            objectType = 'Invoice Header';
            process = 'DirectDebitBatch';
            action = 'UPDATE';
            errorMessage = '';
            recordId = 'Account: '+ invoiceHeadersToUpdate[idx].Account__c;
            for (Database.Error err: resultsPA[idx].getErrors()) {
                errors += 'Account where the error occurred: ' + invoiceHeadersToUpdate[idx].Account__c + ' on Bank Statement creation --- The following error has occurred - ' + err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage() + ' Fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields() + '\n';
                errorMessage += 'The following error has occurred - ' + err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage() + ' Fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields() + '\n';
            }
            LogRegister log = new LogRegister(objectType, process, action, recordId, errorMessage);
            logs.add(log);
        }
        else {
            objectType = 'Invoice Header';
            process = 'DirectDebitBatch';
            action = 'UPDATE';
            errorMessage = '';
            recordId = resultsIH[idx].getId();
            LogRegister log = new LogRegister(objectType, process, action, recordId, errorMessage);
            logs.add(log);
        }
    }





    //BRUNO - added this code because if an error happens when creating a payment allocation and
    //        a bank statement is created without any payment allocation, it should be deleted
    Set<Id> bsIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Bank_Statement__c bs : bankStatementsToCreate) {
        bsIds.add(bs.Id);
    }

    List<PaymentAllocation__c> payments = [SELECT Id, BankstatementId__c FROM PaymentAllocation__c WHERE BankstatementId__c IN :bsIds];
    List<Bank_Statement__c> bsToDelete = new List<Bank_Statement__c>();
    Set<Id> existingBS = new Set<Id>();
    for (PaymentAllocation__c pa : payments) {
        system.debug(pa);
        existingBS.add(pa.BankstatementId__c);
    }
    List<Bank_Statement__c> bankStatementsToUpdate = new List<Bank_Statement__c>();
    for (Bank_Statement__c bs : bankStatementsToCreate) {
        if (!existingBS.contains(bs.Id)) {
            bsToDelete.add(bs);
        }
        else {
            //Update to populate extra fields required by Beth, that are based on the AmountAlloc__c field.
            finalBankStatementList.add(bs);
        }
    }
    if (bsToDelete.size() > 0) {
        Database.DeleteResult[] resultsBsDel = Database.delete(bsToDelete, false);
        for (Integer idx = 0; idx < resultsBsDel.size(); idx++) {
            if (!resultsBsDel[idx].isSuccess()) {

                objectType = 'Bank Statement';
                process = 'DirectDebitBatch';
                action = 'DELETE';
                errorMessage = '';
                recordId = bsToDelete[idx].Id;
                for (Database.Error err: resultsPA[idx].getErrors()) {
                    errorMessage += 'The following error has occurred - ' + err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage() + ' Fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields() + '\n';
                }
                LogRegister log = new LogRegister(objectType, process, action, recordId, errorMessage);
                logs.add(log);
            } else {
                objectType = 'Bank Statement';
                process = 'DirectDebitBatch';
                action = 'DELETE';
                errorMessage = '';
                recordId = resultsBsDel[idx].getId();
                LogRegister log = new LogRegister(objectType, process, action, recordId, errorMessage);
                logs.add(log);
            }
        }
    }

    LogRegister.createLogs(logs);



}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    system.debug('entrei no finish');
    String subject = 'Direct Debit';
    String body = 'You will find attached to this email a CSV file containing the results of the Direct Debit Remittance </br>';
    if (String.isNotBlank(errors)) { 
        body += errors;
    }
    String finalstr = 'Account Name, Total Amount including VAT , Sort Code, Account Number \n';
    String attName = 'DirectDebit.csv';

    // get accounts
    system.debug(accounts.size());
    for (AccountAmount a: accounts) {
        string recordString = '"' + a.accountName + '","' + a.amount + '","' + a.sortCode + '","' + a.accountNumber + '"\n';
        finalstr = finalstr + recordString;
    }
    // Define the email
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    // Create the email attachment    
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa.setFileName(attName);
    efa.setBody(Blob.valueOf(finalstr));

    // Set the paramaters to the email object
    email.setSubject(subject);

    // Create the email Address
    email.setToAddresses(new String[] {
        'brunocunhamendes@rolling-space.pt', 'nunocarvalho1997@hotmail.com'//, 'integration@thefirstmile.co.uk'
    }); //accounts@thefirstmile.co.uk
    email.setHtmlBody(body);

    // Attach file using setFileAttachments function
    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {
        efa
    });

    // Sends the email
    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r =
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {
            email
        });
    system.debug(finalBankStatementList);
    update finalBankStatementList;

    }

}
```

TEST CLASS:

```
@isTest
static String TestcreateBankStatements(){

    string error = ' ';
    string accountsjson = '[{"accountId":"0014E00000mwESFQA2","accountName":"Gurukripa","accountNumber":"53932664","amount":73.7,"invoicesToBePaid":[{"Account__c":"0014E00000mwESFQA2","Id":"a244E000001QQBjQAO","AmountOutstanding__c":73.7}],"numberOfAccounts":599,"sortCode":"208915"}]';

    Account novaConta1 = new Account(
        Name = 'TESTE Account',
        Enqix_Payment_Method__c = 'Direct Debit',
        Payment_Account_Number__c = '123',
        Payment_Sort_Code__c = '321',
        Credit_Days__c = 200       
    );
    insert novaConta1;
    system.debug('NOVA INVOICE'+ novaConta1);

    Invoice_Header__c header = new Invoice_Header__c(
        Name = 'TESTE header',
        Account__c = novaConta1.Id,
        Salesforce__c = false,
        CreatedDate__c = Date.newInstance(2017, 11, 11),
        Query__c = False,
        AmountOutstanding__c = 2000 
    );
    insert header;

    List<Invoice_Header__c> invoices = [Select Id, Query__c, ToPublish__c, Account__c, AmountOutstanding__c, Salesforce__c, Payment_Due_Date__c, Overdue_Days__c from Invoice_Header__c Where Id = :header.Id];

    Bank_Statement__c bankS = new Bank_Statement__c (
        Account__c = novaConta1.Id,
        Entry_Date__c = System.today(),
        Transaction_Details__c = novaConta1.Name + ' Direct Debit Payment',
        Transaction_Type__c = 'Direct Debit',
        Document_name__c = 'Direct Debit Remittance '+ System.today(),
        IsDirectDebit__c = True,
        Customer_Reference__c = novaConta1.Name + System.today() + ' DD Remittance'
    );

    PaymentAllocation__c PayAllo = new PaymentAllocation__c(
        InvoiceId__c = header.Id,
        BankstatementId__c = bankS.Id,
        Account__c = bankS.Account__c,
        AllocatedAmount__c = header.AmountOutstanding__c,
        IsDirectDebit__c = true
    );

    DirectDebitBatch.AccountAmount aa = new DirectDebitBatch.AccountAmount(novaConta1.Id, novaConta1.Name, novaConta1.Payment_Sort_Code__c, novaConta1.AccountNumber, header.AmountOutstanding__c, invoices);
    aa.accountId = novaConta1.Id;
    aa.accountName = novaConta1.Name;
    aa.sortCode = novaConta1.Payment_Sort_Code__c;
    aa.accountNumber = novaConta1.AccountNumber;
    aa.amount = header.AmountOutstanding__c;
    aa.invoicesToBePaid = invoices;

    Test.startTest();

        DirectDebitBatch obj = new DirectDebitBatch();
        Database.executebatch(obj, 3);

    Test.stopTest();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be tough for anyone other than you to debug due to the high complexity of the data model and your query. Based upon your description of your code coverage, it sounds like your `start()` method's query is returning no results, and hence not running `execute()`.

Based only on the code you have shared, I see that your query looks for Accounts which have `Invoice_Header__c` records with `ToPublish__c = true` and `Overdue_Days__c > 0`. Your test code does not explicitly populate these fields. If they are not populated by other automation in your org, the absence of these field values may be the source of the problem.